# How to update MyIsam table concurrently?

Tags: mysql

I am having a MyIsam table with more than 1 million records. I need to update each row this table. I am processing the records batch wise and i have written a kind of muti thread script for it. each thread of script will process only a batch of record.

Now the issue is when two batches running concurrently, one update is waiting to get the the other update to finish. Is it possible to avoid this delay? Specifically is it possible to update records in a database concurrently?

In my case no row is depending on other rows and it will not over written again.

I have read about TL_WRITE_ALLOW_WRITE. But dont know how to implement it?

Can anyone suggest a best solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot do that with MyIsam tables since any attempt to edit will lock the table. On InnoDB however you can do that.

Comment: I actually tried to convert my table to InnoDb and run the job. It takes more time than the myIsam.

Comment: InnoDB has better performance in same cases.Are your table correctly indexed?Did you compare EXPLAIN query between InnodBD and MyISAM?